# Does/can Valgrind use multiple processors?

Tags: c++, profiling, multicore, valgrind

Is there a way to get valgrind to use multiple processors?

I'm doing some bottleneck profiling with valgrind's callgrind and noticed significantly different resource usage behavior in my application vs when run outside of valgrind/callgrind.

When run outside valgrind, it maxes out several processors, but run inside valgrind only uses one. This makes me worry that my bottle necks will be in different places, and thus invalidate my profiling.

Comment: Can't you use another profiler, e.g: `oprofile`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the Valgrind Docs, they do not support multiple processors:

> The main thing to point out with
>   respect to threaded programs is that
>   your program will use the native
>   threading library, but Valgrind
>   serialises execution so that only one
>   (kernel) thread is running at a time.
>   This approach avoids the horrible
>   implementation problems of
>   implementing a truly multithreaded
>   version of Valgrind, but it does mean
>   that threaded apps run only on one
>   CPU, even if you have a multiprocessor
>   or multicore machine.
>
> Valgrind doesn't schedule the threads
>   itself. It merely ensures that only
>   one thread runs at once, using a
>   simple locking scheme. The actual
>   thread scheduling remains under
>   control of the OS kernel. What this
>   does mean, though, is that your
>   program will see very different
>   scheduling when run on Valgrind than
>   it does when running normally. This is
>   both because Valgrind is serialising
>   the threads, and because the code runs
>   so much slower than normal.
>
> This difference in scheduling may
>   cause your program to behave
>   differently, if you have some kind of
>   concurrency, critical race, locking,
>   or similar, bugs. In that case you
>   might consider using the tools
>   Helgrind and/or DRD to track them
>   down.

Comment: Does applies to only Memcheck, or all tools, like Helgrind?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at:

http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.pthreads_perf_sched

They added:

```
--fair-sched option
```

It may help.